# Regex : How to extract some fields in text

Tags: c#, regex

I've a text file that contains below informations :

```
add comment=user1 disabled=yes name=userA password=123456 profile=\
    Internet-128K service=pppoe
add name=user2 password=123 profile=Internet-2M service=pppoe
add disabled=yes name=user3 password=316 profile=Internet-2M service=\
    pppoe
add disabled=yes name=user4 password=1216 profile=Internet-512K service=\
    pppoe
add caller-id=8C:89:A5:68:18:9A name=user5 password=308 profile=\
    Internet-256K remote-ipv6-prefix=::/64 service=pppoe
...
```

as you can see each row starts with `add` that contains some information(fields) for example `comment, disabled, name, password, profile` and so on. now I want to extract those pieces of information(fields) in each row. How can I do that?

Comment: So what are your thoughts on solving the problem.

Comment: how do you want to do it? 
all comment in one line ? extract in what way?

Comment: So, that's my question. as I mentioned each row starts with add other data are its fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can extract each block, second you extract all information:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("sample.txt");
string[] items = Regex.Matches(text, "add .*?(?=\r\nadd|$)", RegexOptions.Singleline)
                      .Cast<Match>()
                      .Select(m => m.Value)
                      .ToArray();
foreach (string item in items)
{
    string line = Regex.Replace(item, @"\\\s*\r\n\s*", string.Empty);
    KeyValuePair<string, string>[] pairs = Regex.Matches(line, @"(?<name>\w+)=(?<value>.*?)(?=\w+=|$)")
                                                .Cast<Match>()
                                                .Select(m => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(m.Groups["name"].Value, m.Groups["value"].Value))
                                                .ToArray();

    Console.WriteLine(line);
    foreach (var pair in pairs)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution not using regex's - seems to work:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> listDict = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>(); 
string[] text = File.ReadAllLines("sample.txt");
text.ToList().ForEach(line =>
{
    IEnumerable<string> kvpList = line.Split(' ').Skip(1);
    Dictionary<string, string> lineDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    kvpList.ToList().ForEach(kvpItem =>
    {
        string[] kvp = kvpItem.Split('=');
        lineDict.Add(kvp[0], kvp[1]);
    });
    listDict.Add(lineDict);
});

//Output for debug purposes
listDict.ForEach(resultLine =>
{
    resultLine.ToList().ForEach(resultPair => Console.Write(String.Format("{0}:{1} ",    resultPair.Key, resultPair.Value)));
    Console.WriteLine();
});
Console.ReadLine();
```